# ソースコード(オブジェクト）は同じで、設定ファイルのみを動的に変更可能にしたインストーラを作成したいです

Tags: c#, visual-studio

インストーラは一つで、ユーザがインストーラを実行した際、
二つの設定ファイルのパターンのどちらかを選択後、
それぞれ異なる設定ファイルがインストールされるような
仕組みを検討しています。

ノウハウのある方教えて頂きたく、よろしくお願い致します。

開発環境は、以下の通りです。
Visual Studio 2015
Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects
.NET Framework4.6.2
Windows 10 または Windows Server 2016,2019
アプリは、Webアプリ、クライアントアプリ両方

カスタムインストーラを作成すれば可能でしょうか？
サンプルソースや参考サイト等でも構いません。

Comment: 使っているインストーラや作成ツールは何でしょう？ 大概の物にはOSの種別・版数の情報を取得・判別して処理を切り替えとか、選択のためのダイアログ表示・結果取得の機能は付いていそうですが。

Comment: Visual Studio 2015  Installer Projectsです。質問に追記しました。

Comment: ズバリ書かれているのは見つからなかったですが、この辺の記事が参考になりそうです。dobon.netのセットアッププロジェクト [目次](https://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/deployment/index.html), [起動条件](https://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/deployment/conditionmanagement.html), [カスタム動作](https://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/deployment/customaction.html) Qiita記事 [...UIとカスタム動作の連動](https://qiita.com/magic_xyz/items/8106c7d9db5684d8eb61), [なつかしの Visual Studio Installer...](https://qiita.com/otagaisama-1/items/39bf6852f0e99c761786)

Comment: もう少し関連がありそうな記事がこれら。[【.net】セットアッププロジェクトで簡易条件分岐](https://mitosuya.net/setup-project-condition), [【T2-311補足】 msi ファイル (Windows Installer) の 64 bit 向けカスタマイズ](https://tsmatz.wordpress.com/2009/08/27/t2-311-msi-windows-installer-64-bit/), [How to setup Installer project with conditional file copying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6595380/9014308)